# Higher order functions usage with str.startswith

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, functools

I have a file which I want to clean commented lines from. **I'd like to use `functools.partial` for the operation**, in something similar to the following manner:

```
from functools import partial

f = open(filetoread, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# Filtering the comment lines
f_func = partial(str.startswith, prefix="#")
lines = filter(f_func, lines)
```

This does not work, apparently because `str.startswith` is a class method. What is the proper way to use `functools.partial` with `str.startswith` so it will work?

Answer (score 6):

You have three problems:

First, `str.startswith` doesn't take keyword arguments, it takes positional arguments only. It's implemented in C, and uses `PyArg_ParseTuple` to get its positional arguments. There's nothing to tell Python what names they have, since the name `prefix` appears only in the docstring. So `prefix=` is no good. The problem is analogous to this:

```
>>> str.startswith('#hi', prefix='#')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: startswith() takes no keyword arguments
>>> def foo(self,prefix,start=None,end=None): return str.startswith(self,prefix,start,end)
...
>>> foo('#hi', prefix='#')
True
```

Second, the first argument of `str.startswith` is not the prefix, it's `self`, the object in which we're checking whether or not it has the prefix. There's no inherent problem with it being a method, you'd be fine if there was a method called `str.isprefixof`, or if this method were implemented in Python. But there isn't and it isn't.

Finally, `functools.partial` only lets you bind the initial positional arguments, it doesn't know how to bind the second but not the first. Since the argument you want to bind isn't the first and isn't accessible by name, you're out of options.

There's a workaround for this case, though, to write functional-style code. You just need `operator.methodcaller`, not `functools.partial`:

```
f_func = operator.methodcaller('startswith', '#')
```

`operator.methodcaller` binds all arguments *except* the first.

---

Since you ask what's the proper way to use `functools`, I suppose you could do so with an extra higher-order function to reverse the arguments:

```
def flip(func):
    return lambda x,y: func(y,x)

f_func = partial(flip(str.startswith), '#')
```

You might consider this "cheating" since it uses a lambda, and if we wanted to use a lambda we'd have used it like in Daniel's answer. But we're using it to implement a basic higher-order function that Python doesn't provide, and once that's out of the way the line to define `f_func` feels nice and functional.

Mind you, I'm not implementing that higher-order function particularly *well* here in Python terms, since I don't provide any meta-data like `partial` does. It has a `func` read-only attribute that users might reasonably want `flip` to provide too.

Alternatively, you could write a Python wrapper to `str.startswith`, like `foo` above, and apply `partial` to that.

Comment: You are wrong regarding the "three problems": a- `str.startswith` has an argument with the name `prefix`, and this is the way to generate higher order function using `partial` when you want to assign arguments not by the order of the signature (regardless if they were keywords arguments). b- This is obvious, and this is why I used the `prefix`. c- As I mentioned, `partial` allows you to set any argument of the function

Comment: Hmm, you make an interesting point. Using the name of a positional argument fails for `str.startswith` (it tries to pass it a keyword argument) but works for `foo` defined as `def foo(self,prefix): return self.startswith(prefix)`.

Comment: Oh, it's probably something to do with how `str.startswith` is implemented in CPython. I bet it uses `PyArg_ParseTuple` (or similar) and as a consequence Python doesn't "know" the names of its arguments. If you write a class in Python with the same method signature, it works.

Comment: Steve- thank you for your remarks. I'll guess I won't be able to use it this way then...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think partial is the right tool here. Instead, you could use a lambda:

```
func = lambda s: s.startswith('#')
lines = filter(func, lines)
```

Although note that Python isn't really a functional language, and a more Pythonic way of doing this would be with a list comprehension:

```
lines = [line for line in lines if line.startswith('#')]
```

Comment: I know partial is not the best way here, this is why I mentioned that *I'd like to use partial* for this problem- That is, even though there are other ways to solve this.